# Debian, Nvidia optimus laptop, dual monitor problem

Tags: debian, nvidia, multi-monitor

I installed Debian 11.3 on a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop that uses a Intel HD Graphics 630 + a Nvidia GP107M (GTX1050Ti) GPUs. Presently the stock i915 and nouveau drivers are used respectively.

I want to have a dual monitor setup where my desktop extends to the secondary HDMI monitor.

While the O/S is booting, a display plugged into the HDMI port mirrors the laptop display. Therefore I do not believe it is a cable/hardware/driver issue of the secondary HDMI monitor not being detected.

Once the Desktop Environment is loaded, the monitor is no longer detected.

I've read the different advice posted on different forums without success. Glxgears gives about 60 FPS, only on the laptop display.

Comment: please repost here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148